# r how to alter several columns based on condition (duplication in another col)

Tags: r, duplicates

i have a data frame like this

```
df <- data.frame(groupx=c("k1","k1","k2","k4","k3","k2"),x1=rep(1,6),x2=rep(2,6),
x3=rep(3,6),y1=rep(4,6),x12=rep(5,6))
```

and for each duplicate row in groups, i wanna modify the several related columns by prefixing the number with 'a'

i'm currently doing it like this and am quite sure it's not the most efficient method:

```
df[duplicated(df$groupx),"x1"]=paste0("a",df[duplicated(df$groupx),"x1"])
df[duplicated(df$groupx),"x2"]=paste0("a",df[duplicated(df$groupx),"x2"])
df[duplicated(df$groupx),"x3"]=paste0("a",df[duplicated(df$groupx),"x3"])
```

The desired output is to have "a" in front of corresponding rows of col x1,x2,x3 but not other columns.

Any recommendations? Thanks

Edit: sorry for the misunderstanding. Groupx row are not related with col names, the earlier example was a coincidence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 xCols <- intersect(df$groupx, colnames(df))
 df[, xCols] <- lapply(df[,xCols], function(x) {indx <- duplicated(df$groupx)
                                     x[indx] <-paste0("a", x[indx]); x })


  df
  #  groupx x1 x2 x3 y1 x12
  #1     x1  1  2  3  4   5
  #2     x1 a1 a2 a3  4   5
  #3     x2  1  2  3  4   5
  #4     x4  1  2  3  4   5
  #5     x3  1  2  3  4   5
  #6     x2 a1 a2 a3  4   5
```

Or

```
  m1 <- as.matrix(df[,xCols])
  indx <- duplicated(df[,1])[row(df[,xCols])]
  m1[indx] <- paste0("a", m1[indx])
  df[,xCols] <- m1
```

Comment: @David Arenburg Thanks for the comment.  I might have messed up. Oh, I see, it is only for columns `x1, x2, x3`.  I was thinking that it is for the whole columns

Comment: This works great. What's the purpose of ';x' at the end of the function in lapply?

Comment: @santoku It is to return the full vector `x` Otherwise, you will have only the `subset`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you want to update only the columns that appear in `df$groupx`, so here's a possible solution

```
indx <- grep(paste0("^", paste(unique(df$groupx), collapse = "$|^"), "$"), names(df))
df[duplicated(df$groupx), indx] <- paste0("a", as.matrix(df[duplicated(df$groupx), indx]))
df
#   groupx  x1  x2  x3 y1 x12
# 1     x1   1   2   3  4   5
# 2     x1  a1  a2  a3  4   5
# 3     x2   1   2   3  4   5
# 4     x4   1   2   3  4   5
# 5     x3   1   2   3  4   5
# 6     x2  a1  a2  a3  4   5
```

Comment: Your `grep` makes more sense as I kept thinking why only x1:x3.

Comment: I didn't communicate clearly earlier. X1-3 are just 3 col related to groupx